# How to move callback handling into service?

Tags: angularjs

The service, using $http

```
myServices.factory('myService', ['$http',
function($http){
    return {xy:   
                function getXy() {
                    return $http.get('http://ip.com/xy');       
                }
            }
  }]);
```

The controller

```
myControllers.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService',
  function($scope, myService) {

    myService.xy().then(function(response){
        $scope.xy= response.data;
    });
```

What is not so nice with this solution, is that the controller has to handle the REST callback. It would be better, if the controller could simply state the following:

```
$scope.xy = myService.xy();
```

How can the callback handling moved into the service?

Comment: What is `response.data`? If it's an array, you can return an empty array and push items into it from within the service when the REST call completes. If it's an object, you can return an empty object and use `angular.extend()` to populate it when REST call returns. But my personal preference is to embrace promises and use `.then()` in the controller. What I would change though is have the service "unpack" the data from response object (the controller shouldn't know that it's a REST call that returns a response object) and perhaps do some error handling / logging.

Comment: @AnthonyChu: I agree, that the controller should not handle the resonse object, but how could this unpacking be done?